# How to change an image within UICollectionViewCell on tap?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to change an image that is displayed inside a UICollectionViewCell on tap. Here is my code:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *cellImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    cellImageView.image = [[allActivities objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] obverseIcon];

    return cell;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"%@ was selected", [[allActivities objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] name]);

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImageView *cellImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];

    Activity *activity = [allActivities objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (activity.isMy)
    {
        activity.isMy = NO;
        cellImageView.image = [[allActivities objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] obverseIcon];
    }
    else
    {
        activity.isMy = YES;
        cellImageView.image = [[allActivities objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] reverseIcon];
    }

    [allActivities replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:activity];
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
```

When I tap a cell, image does not change.

Comment: Whats activity class ? Also you could replace "    [self.collectionView reloadData];" with "[self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];" this will reload that selectedRow only

Comment: Activity contains among other things fields UIImage *obverse and UIImage *reverseIcon. Changing to [self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]] didn't solve a problem.

Comment: That replacement was just to avoid the reload of whole collectionView as only one row is required to reload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
- (UICollectionViewCellSubclass *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UICollectionViewCellSubclass *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Activity *activity = allActivities[indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image = activity.isMy ? activity.obverseIcon : activity.reverseIcon;
    return cell;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Activity *activity = allActivities[indexPath.row];
    activity.isMy = !activity.isMy;
    [self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];
}
```

where `UICollectionViewCellSubclass` is your custom class which inherit from `UICollectionViewCell` and implement:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageView;
```

Comment: Now I see no cells at all and I get logs: _UICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied:_, _Could not load the "" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.epstim.CapTime"_

Comment: OK, fixed! UIImageView *imageView should be **IBOutlet**. Thank you!

Comment: I assumed you create UI programmatically ;) Nevertheless it good to hear that you resolved you this issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create custom cell class with super class UICollectionViewCell.
2. Create an outlet from your cell's image to that class .h file.
3. In your didSelectItemAtIndexPath method replace UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
   with your cell's class name.
4. Change the image. For example cell.imageView.hidden = YES;

Answer (score -1):

```
- (__kindof UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    questionImageCollectionViewCell * cell=[self.questionCollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"coustomCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.optionImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[_optionImageArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];
     [cell.rightTickImg setHidden:YES];
    if(self.array==nil)
        {
            [cell.rightTickImg setHidden:YES];
        }
    else
        {
            [cell.rightTickImg setHidden:YES];
            NSDictionary *dic = self.array[indexPath.row];
            NSLog(@"ouput DIC=%@",dic);
            NSLog(@"objeject for key=%@",[dic objectForKey:@"option"]);

   // if ([dic[@"option"] boolValue])
        if([[dic objectForKey:@"option"] isEqualToString:@"1"])

    {
        [cell.rightTickImg setHidden:NO];
    }
else
    {
  [cell.rightTickImg setHidden:YES];
    }

    }

return cell;
```

}

```
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
return 

CGSizeMake(collectionView.frame.size.width/2.2,collectionView.frame.size.height/2.3);
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{



     [self dicData];
    NSLog(@"First=%@",self.array);
     [self.array removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSDictionary *dic = @{@"option":@"1"};
    [self.array insertObject:dic atIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"Second=%@",self.array);

    NSMutableArray * indexArry=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (NSInteger i=0; i< _optionImageArr.count; i++)
    {
        NSIndexPath * index =[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0] ;
        [indexArry addObject:index];
        NSLog(@"%@",indexArry);


    }
     [collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:indexArry];


}
```

1. Heading